# Why $stateProvider doesn't work in ionic real device?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have declared a state using `$stateProvider`. The state looks like this:

```
.state('tabs.chat1', {
    url : "/chat/:id",
    views : {
        'chat1-tab' : {
            templateUrl : "templates/chat1.html",
            controller : "chatController1"
        }
    }
```

In HTML I have a link with `href="/chat/:{{user._id}}`. In the browser it works fine, but when I run it on an Android device tells me that the link doesn't exist. Any ideas?

Comment: might be some problem with build . it works using ionic serve ?

Comment: Yes.i use ionic serve when i run in browser and it works :(

Comment: @Creator you could use `ui-sref="tabs.chat1(id: user._id)"`

Comment: ok..but how can i define the state?..i.ve modified the html and i have a lot of errors

Comment: yeah he can try that . But href works fine though @PankajParkar

Comment: any idea @PankajParkar ?

Comment: Did you tried: `href="#/chat/:{{user._id}}` ?

Comment: Resolved :)..Thanks @PankajParkar .Your answer is good :)..with a small mistake : ui-sref="tabs.chat1({id: user._id})"

Comment: Thanks for help guys :)

Comment: Yes...is ok :) .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't directly define `href` like this while you have `ui-sref` directive provided by `ui-router` to create a `href` dynamically. Mention state name in it and then provide requires `params` in its `JSON`, Though other way of fixing it would be `href="/chat/{{user._id}}` but I don't encourage you to do this.

```
ui-serf="tabs.chat1(id: user._id)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Href should look like this

```
href="#/chat/{{user._id}}"
```

no need for the : since the : means that it is a variable that will be fed from a link. we use a # because its loading a template not an entire new page.